# Extract data into array from foreach

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, foreach

Please go easy on me, this is my first time and obviously I have no idea what I'm doing...

I am using the following script that I found online to upload files and write the upload information into a database, I would like to collect the $file_name information into another array to be used outside of this code block in an implode function. I've searched high and low but have been unsuccessful in my searching. I figured out how to print the $file_name(s) from inside the if statement but not outside of both it and the php block but I can't figure out how to make it into an array instead.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <?php
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $errors= array();
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
        $timestamp= date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
        if($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }       
        $query="INSERT into upload_data (FILE_NAME, FILE_SIZE, FILE_TYPE, timestamp) VALUES(:file_name,:file_size,:file_type, :timestamp)";
        $desired_dir="files";
        if(empty($errors)==true){
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"files/".$file_name);
            }else{                                  //rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="files/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
            }
            $q = $dbo->prepare($query);     
            $q->execute(array(':file_name'=>$file_name,':file_size'=>$file_size,':file_type'=>$file_type, ':timestamp'=>$timestamp));

        }else{
                print_r($errors);
        }
    }
    if(empty($error)){
        echo "Success";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly, try creating an empty array before your foreach loop, you can the populate that array when you're inside the loop and then read from it later on

Comment: you just want those file names outside in an array. Am I correct?

Comment: Tushar - yes that's correct, I have a second PHP block that I'd like to use the data in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your understanding (as you said you are new)

***In PHP***
An array can be created using the `array()` language construct. It takes any number of comma-separated `key => value` pairs as arguments.

```
Example #1 A simple array

<?php
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
);

// as of PHP 5.4
$array = [
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
];

?>
```

Now for your concern you just have to put all chopped out data from the foreach loop into a new array as:

```
 <?php
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $errors= array();
    $filename_array = array();
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $filename_array[] = $file_name;
          $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
    $timestamp= date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
    if($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
    }       
    $query="INSERT into upload_data (FILE_NAME, FILE_SIZE, FILE_TYPE, timestamp) VALUES(:file_name,:file_size,:file_type, :timestamp)";
    $desired_dir="files";
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
            mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
        }
        if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"files/".$file_name);
        }else{                                  //rename the file if another one exist
            $new_dir="files/".$file_name.time();
             rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
        }
        $q = $dbo->prepare($query);     
        $q->execute(array(':file_name'=>$file_name,':file_size'=>$file_size,':file_type'=>$file_type, ':timestamp'=>$timestamp));

    }else{
            print_r($errors);
    }
}
if(empty($error)){
    echo "Success";
}
}

?>
```

*Now in your second block get the file names as*

```
foreach ($filename_array as $filename) {
    echo $filename;
}
```

Refer for understanding [PHP Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Tushar this works great, Thank you. How would I go about imploding the filename information? I'm getting invalid argument errors on my implode.

Comment: How you want to implode ...can you update your full ques with an example...that would help thanks

Comment: I have tried variants of the following:
foreach ($filename_array as $filename) {
    $xxx= implode($_POST['filename'], ", ");
 echo $filename;
echo $xxx;
}

Comment: why have you used $_POST

Comment: Being new I thought I had to, I tried without and it works great, thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Set an array before the loop:

```
$file_name_array = array();
```

Put the following code on the line after $file_name.

```
$file_name_array[] = $file_name;
```

This will give you an array containing the contents on $file_name, and will add to the array on each pass with each one.

Then you can do whatever you wish with the array.

Answer (score 0):

Declare an array:

```
$file_names();
```

Add this line inside loop after `$file_name`:

```
$file_names[] = $file_name;
```

This `$file_names` will give you name of all the files.