# Convert imploded array results into url strings

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, implode

I have an array of files that I implode and get a result like
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt

I need to take **each** of those results and turn them into hyperlinks based on their filename that I can then write to a single column of a database database so echo won't work. I've tried concatenation, modifying the implode, etc. and nothing has worked so far.

Optimal results are generically something like this:

```
<a href="file1.txt">file1.txt</a>
<a href="file2.txt">file2.txt</a>
<a href="file3.txt">file3.txt</a>
```

Thoughts?

```
foreach ($filename_array as $filename) {
$foo = implode('<br>',$filename_array);
}
echo $foo;
```

returns 
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt

```
$foo= '<a href="'.$desired_dir.'/';
$foo.= implode($filename_array);
$foo.= '">';
$foo.= implode($filename_array);
$foo.= '</a><br />';
echo $foo;
```

returns

```
<a href="file1.txtfile2.txtfile3.txt">file1.txtfile2.txtfile3.txt</a> (this is a generalization, not the actual code)
```

a < ignore this it's not in the code

```
foreach ($filename_array as $filename) {
$foo = implode('<br>',$filename_array);
}

echo '<a href="'.$desired_dir.'/'.$foo.'">'.$foo.'</a><br />';
```

returns something like

```
<a href="file1.txt<br> file2.txt<br> file3.txt">file1.txt</a>
<a href="file1.txt<br> file2.txt<br> file3.txt">file2.txt</a>
<a href="file1.txt<br> file2.txt<br> file3.txt">file3.txt</a>
```

Please be gentle, I'm VERY VERY new to phpland and am trying my hardest.

Comment: Could you provide us the actual input? Where is that data coming from, database?

Comment: Input is derived from this code (answer #3) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25794841/extract-data-into-array-from-foreach/25795362?noredirect=1#comment40346643_25795362

Comment: foreach(), no implode

Comment: $filename_array = array();
   .
        $filename_array[] = $file_name;

Comment: @Dagon

`code` foreach ($filename_array as $filename) {
$foo = '<a href="'.$desired_dir.'/'.$filename.'">'.$filename.'</a><br />';

}
echo $foo;

doesn't return all my items, just the first one with a proper url

Comment: @user4032063 see my code, you are overwritting $foo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no implode required

```
$foo=''; //initate the string so you don't get a warning on the first iteration
foreach ($filename_array as $filename) {
$foo .= '<a href="'.$filename.'">'.$filename.'</a>'; //add to the string with concationatin .=
}

echo $foo;
```

if you want to echo directly and not store the results in a variable:

```
foreach ($filename_array as $filename) {
echo '<a href="'.$filename.'">'.$filename.'</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($arr as $item) echo '<a href="' . $item . '">' . $item . '</a>';
```